# Android AVD with Google Play Services on Circle.ci

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-virtual-device, circleci

I am using circle.ci to test my code on an emulator.

I have some espresso tests wich are using maps and places api from google. Those tests are not working with the emulator given by circle.ci

So I tried to do my own, in the circle.yml

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: "~/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/gradle-2.9/bin:$PATH"
    TERM: "dumb"
    ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "10"
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'

dependencies:
  pre:
    - android list targets
    - wget "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-bin.zip"; unzip gradle-2.9-bin.zip
    - android list sdk -a -e
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.2
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tool,android-22,extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository,addon-google_apis-google-22
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-22
test:
  override:
    - echo no | android create avd -n avd22 -t 12 --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
    - emulator -avd avd22 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
```

Sadly, even I when I run `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-22` if I do a `android list target` it appear that my image is not availble :

```
id: 12 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 5.1.1 (API level 22)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

If someone has a solution to use an emulator on circle.ci with play services it would be really useful for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of try I could finally create a Android AVD with play services using this config file:

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: "~/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/gradle-2.9/bin:$PATH"
    TERM: "dumb"
    ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "10"
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
dependencies:
  pre:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-22
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.2
    - echo y | android update sdk -a -u -t sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-22
    - android list targets
test:
  override:
    - echo no | android create avd -n custom-android22-googleapis -t "android-22" --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
    - android list avd
    - emulator -avd custom-android22-googleapis -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    # wait for emulator to have booted
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # Sleeping isn't a brilliant fix...
    - sleep 30
    - fb-adb rcmd screencap -p > $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/screen-$(date +"%T").png
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex --console=plain --info
    #- fb-adb devices
    - fb-adb rcmd screencap -p > $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/screen-$(date +"%T").png
```

Comment: I have this working as well but now have a problem where a dialog blocks the UI. It says the emulator needs updated Google Play services but updating doesn't appear to work. Wondering if you ran into this issue as well and if you have a fix